# What is the best way to include a template file within a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

I'm writing a shortcode for a child-theme.

I want to load a php template file to generate my HTML and then output this HTML in a string to return this string. But I don't know the best way to do this. The Codex mentions the `ob_start` function but it seems to me a bit dirty.

Are there any template functions (like those in PHP frameworks when you load a view) to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress doesn't bundle any "templating engine" libraries like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) or [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), as far as I am aware, and frankly I have not been sold on the need for them. (Yes, I know its all the rage.)

Concatenate your own strings, use PHP native functions like `ob_start` or `sprintf`, or load your own templating library. I have seen plugins do that. I just recently saw one that loaded Mustache, and there is a [WordPress plugin purporting to make Smarty available](http://wordpress.org/plugins/smarty-for-wordpress/).

Comment: Thank you, it's a complete answer ! I'll use `ob_start`, I don't want to concatenate more than 50 HTML lines. Hopefully one day WP will publish this feature.

Comment: I hope WordPress _doesn't_ incorporate this additional layer of code that has to be read, parsed, and executed.